# How to update two arguments at the same time using Ruby Observer method?

Tags: ruby, design-patterns

I am studying Ruby's [Design Pattern](http://designpatternsinruby.com/) and came across Observer method. I tried to customize my own observer method to help me understand it but it returns an error. Here is what I came up with:

```
class YummyTastyDonut
    def update(changed_order)
        puts "Kitchen: Yo, change the order to #{changed_order.order}!"
        puts "Front: Order for #{changed_order.name}!"
        puts "Front: The price will now be #{changed_order.order_price} "
    end
end


class Customer
    attr_reader :name, :order
    attr_accessor :order_price

    def initialize(name, order, order_price)
        @name = name
        @order = order
        @order_price = order_price
        @observers = []
    end

    def order=(new_order, new_price)
        @order = new_order
        @order_price = new_price
        notify_observers
    end

    def notify_observers
        @observers.each do |observer|
            observer.update(self)
        end
    end

    def add_observer(observer)
        @observers << observer
    end

    def delete_observer(observer)
        @observers.delete(observer)
    end
end
```

If you read the book, I changed the class names, but the essence is the same. One thing I changed is `order=` method; it now accepts two arguments instead of one.

The goal is, after creating new `Customer`, I want the new customer to be able to change my order and notify `YummyTastyDonut`. However, I want to be able to update two things: the `order` and `order_price` (obviously, if I change my order, the price will also change). I want `YummyTastyDonut` to respond to my change.

```
igg = Customer.new("Iggy", "Bacon Donut", 10)
=> #<Customer:0x0056212e48a940 @name="Iggy", @order="Bacon Donut", @order_price=10, @observers=[]>

donut = YummyTastyDonut.new
=> #<YummyTastyDonut:0x0056212e4894c8>

## Updating my order and order_price ##

   igg.order = ("yummy butter donut", 15)
#(repl):1: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
#igg.order = ("yummy butter donut", 15)
```

If I use this `order=` method that accepts only one argument, it works just as expected.

```
def order=(new_order)
    @order = new_order
    notify_observers
end

 igg.order = "Triple bacon donut explosion"
Kitchen: Yo, change the order to Triple bacon donut explosion!
Front: Order for Iggy!
Front: The price will now be 10
```

What do I have to change so I can update both `order` and `order_price` simultaneously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assignment `=` is meant to accept a single argument to be assigned.(or the same number of elements as variables in the event of parallel assignment)

You could do this as:

```
def order=(args)
  @order = args[0]
  @order_price = args[1]
  notify_observers
end
```

Then call like

```
igg.order=["yummy butter donut", 15]
```

or use an options `Hash` as @BartekGladys suggested but both solutions seem awful and fallible to say the least and would require knowledge of the internals of the method in order to utilize it correctly.

Also currently even if this method worked it would be extremely confusing to future you or anyone looking at your code base because you have an instance variable `@order` so the assumption would be `order=(val)` would assign that variable.

You would be better off with a method called `change_order` that accepts `order` and `order_price` and this would eliminate all confusion as to whats happening.

```
def change_order(new_order, new_price)
    @order = new_order
    @order_price = new_price
    notify_observers
end
```

and then reading it makes more sense too.

```
igg = Customer.new("Iggy", "Bacon Donut", 10)
#Currently seems like it is assigning order to an Array maybe? 
igg.order=("yummy butter donut", 15)
#New much clearer as to the implementation and purpose of changing an order
igg.change_order("yummy butter donut", 15)
```

Comment: Such a simple solution! Why didn't I think of that? Thanks!! Also, thanks for pointing out that `=` can only accept 1 arg. I didn't know that before. That knowledge will come in handy :)

Answer (score 1):

It's very weird error, but i find solution that can help you. You can use one argument and include 2 values there.

```
def order=(opts={})
    @order = opts[:new_order]
    @order_price = opts[:new_price]
    notify_observers
end
```

and call this function:

```
igg.order= {new_order: 'yumyy better donut', new_price: 15 }
```

Comment: That makes sense! Didn't think of using hash before. Thank you!